# Android Studio Gradle Sync Failed: make failed with exit status 2

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk, openframeworks

I'm trying to build openFrameworks's AndroidEmptyExample using Android Studio on OSX.

I followed this instruction http://openframeworks.cc/setup/android-studio/ but it fails with the "make failed with exit status 2" error message during the Gradle Sync process.[image]

I tried everything I can do but it's not working. 
I'm using r10e version for NDK. and 3.3 Gradle version and 2.3.3 Android Plugin Version. And I have tried both API 22 and API 26 but it doesn't work.

I would appreciate any advice. Thanks!

Comment: Connect your system to Internet and re-sync the gradle. May be it will help you. I'm not sure but just try this option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue with openFrameworks and Android studio. There is a pull request in the queue https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks/pull/5461 that should solve this problem.  Please try it out.

There is a discussion of your specific problem here here as well https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks/issues/5456

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I re-installed Android Studio and somehow it worked without the error.